# Java Swing issue, why is a changeEvent firing extra events with a jButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, changelistener

While trying to learn JButton events I'm getting confused because of a problem.  The sample code I'm using is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofbuttoneventsincludingActionItemandChangeeventtypes.htm).

The code is below:

```
jb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Changed");
    }
});
```

This is a demo application so only one button is used and it has the focus when the  application is starting up. I simply press the spacebar to simulate a click event. As per the tutorial (by OReilly: Java Swing) it should fire the change event twice followed by an action event followed by action event. i.e.

1. Changed
2. Changed
3. ActionEvent
4. Changed

But after the 4th event I got another ChangeEvent. There is actually 5 events for a single click in the way mentioned above.  If I'm trying to click with mouse the result is even more different. When the mouse entered into the button region, an event fired.

I don't know what change occurs and ChangeEvent is raised when the mouse hovers over the JButton.  I don't find a similar method like getChangedState (ItemStageChanged) for JButton to know what state changed in that button.  Since it's about learning, I don't want to use ActionListener unless I understand this issue.

So my questions are:

1. Why do I see the ChangeEvent twice where it should be one?
2. How do I find what state is changed in JButton?

Edit:
I see there are 5 states mentioned in DefaultButtonModel and they are defined in ButtonModel interface. But JButton don't have fields,methods to get those states. did they get ignored willingly? Or JButton(and AbstractButton) don't relates with ButtonModel interface.

Edit 2:
The tutorial indicates,

> Depending on the L&F, there may also be additional ChangeEvents.

I'm using Swing's default L&F in Windows but I'm getting different results than tutorial's expectation.

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to use `JButton` or how to use `ChangeListener`?  I ask because in all the time I've coded Java, I've never found a reason to add a `ChangeListener` to a button.  An `ActionListener` is the usual way to go..

Comment: While Studying JButton chapter, I got this. However I don't want to ignore it **even if it's not used** much.

Comment: Agree with Andrew. In any case I would start with the Swing tutorials for explanation/examples on [How to Write a Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html). In your case you get one event when the button is selected and one event when it is unselected.

Comment: @camickr nitpicking: a plain JButton can't be selected <g> To OP: the exact number of ChangeEvents is hard to predict: they are fired whenever a property of the buttonModel is changed (like armed, pressed, or rollover when triggered by the mouse)

Comment: @kleopatra, yes I meant "pressed".

Comment: @kleopatra - The DefaultButtonModel and JButton don't have any sort of relationship?

Comment: @Jones don't understand what you mean ...

Comment: OReily's book says, DefaultButtonModel class is directly used by AbstractButton. JButton extends AbstractButton. If DefaultButtonModel implements ButtonModel which has isArmed method, why not JButton has such one?

Comment: don't know: it's a design decision to either add cover methods on the user component (the button) or not, the swing team decided not to for the model. A reason might be (guessing only, of course) that the model properties typically aren't needed by application code, so there's no need to clutter the api

Comment: @kleopatra - Thanks. You can answer it as it comes close. Any idea on why it fired twice? (though you said it's hard to predict!)

Comment: `Any idea on why it fired twice?` - already answered! In fact both of your original questions are answered.

Answer (score 2):

The five events that happen when you press the button, in order are:
ChangeEvent: Armed - true
ChangeEvent: Pressed - true
ActionEvent
ChangeEvent: Pressed - false
ChangeEvent: Armed - false

If you use your mouse to press the button then in addition to the above, 
there will be a ChangeEvent for Rollover: true when the mouse moves over the button and another for Rollever: false when the mouse moves away from the button.